# How to build LWP::UserAgent form parameters dynamically?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I want to build a set of form parameters for use in an HTTP POST on the fly, but I'm not sure how to access/build the data structure LWP::UserAgent uses dynamically.

The typical example code has this structure being passed as a request.

```
my $response = $browser->post(
  'http://example.com/postme',
  [
    'param1'  => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2'
  ],
);
```

I have a set of parameter names and values stored in a hash, and I want to build the structure in the square brackets from my hash data. What is that structure, and how can I do what I want to do? (as you can tell, I'm no perl expert!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square brackets construct an arrayref, but in this case the `post` method accepts either an arrayref or a hashref.  So you can just do:

```
my %params;
$params{param1} = 'value1'; # store parameters into %params here
my $response = $browser->post('http://example.com/postme', \%params);
```

Read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for an introduction to references, and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more details.